# Remote Webdriver how to achieve this requirement

Tags: java, selenium, webdriver, testng

We need to run below steps in scenario and not able to achieve.

Using `POM` framework -

Below is the scenario -

1. Start Hub
2. start Node 1 and Node 2
3. Instantiate remote webdriver with default capabilites
4. Inside Single Test -

   a. update cabilities to match with node 1

   b. run code under annotation @Test which will open webpage and login user1

   c. update cabilities to match with node 2

   d. run code under annotation @Test which will open webpage and login user2

   e. update cabilities to match with node 1

   f. run code under annotation @Test which will logout user1

   g. update cabilities to match with node 2

   h. run code under annotation @Test which will logout user2
5. Run the test using TestNg

Currently I am trying to use `Selenium GRID` but not working.

Comment: specifically what is it that you are having trouble with?  Can you show us some code and the error(s) that you are getting?

Comment: What have you tried to achieve this requirement? Show us some code, exception, error etc.

Comment: Hi,  I am not getting any exception but all commands get executed on single machine. my code as below -